# If an email bounces back from one recipient have the others received it?

Tags: email

When sending an email to multiple people if an email bounces back from one recipient have the others received it?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is the normal behavior of any MTA I've worked with. Just because an email bonces to one of the recipients, doesn't mean it bounced to all of them, you'll get an NDR for each recipient that it bounces for, or one with all recipients that the MTA could not send to.

If you are seeing that your message is not being delivered to all recipients you probably have something else going on.

What MTA are you using?

Comment: Thanks, I only got one bounce so I must have the wrong address, I'm using Exchange.

Comment: @Mark: Correct, !bounced != delivered

Answer (score 3):

The short answer: Probably - This is how most mail transport agents handle it.

The long answer: "There is no guarantee on delivery of email, it is a best effort service. Some sites best effort will include sending Lassie herself to bring the email to the users, other sites will throw it in a pile and forget they ever received it".

(This is like my favorite question: "Did you get the last email I sent you?", to which I always reply "I don't know what the last email *you sent* was, however the last email *I received* said xxxxx" :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, though if you have many recipients and a high bounce rate, you will look spammy.